# JS/jQuery - Массив из Dom-элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть такой код в HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <img src="images/user1.jpg" style="opacity:0.5" width="90px" height="90px">
  <img src="images/user2.jpg" width="90px" height="90px">
  <img src="images/user3.jpg" style="opacity:0.5" width="90px" height="90px">
</div>
```

Как сделать из этих изображений массив на JS/JQ?

Comment: Всем Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **JavaScript**

```js
var container = document.getElementById("slider");
console.log(Array.from(container.children));
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <img src="images/user1.jpg" style="opacity:0.5" width="90px" height="90px">
  <img src="images/user2.jpg" width="90px" height="90px">
  <img src="images/user3.jpg" style="opacity:0.5" width="90px" height="90px">
</div>
```

2. **jQuery**

```js
console.log($("#slider").children().toArray())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <img src="images/user1.jpg" style="opacity:0.5" width="90px" height="90px">
  <img src="images/user2.jpg" width="90px" height="90px">
  <img src="images/user3.jpg" style="opacity:0.5" width="90px" height="90px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgArray = [];

$.each($('div#slider img'), function (index, element){
 imgArray.push($(element).attr('src'));
});

console.log(imgArray);
```